# Error while adding WMS layer in QGis 2.18.13

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wms

I already set up a geoserver instance and add some raster stores to it. I want to use them as WMS service through different application like QGIS and AutoCAD but when I try to add the WMS layer in QGIS 2.18.13 I get this error:

```
Invalid Layer: WMS provider Cannot calculate extent Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: wms, URI: IgnoreAxisOrientation=1&IgnoreGetFeatureInfoUrl=1&IgnoreGetMapUrl=1&contextualWMSLegend=0&crs=EPSG:32634&dpiMode=7&featureCount=10&format=image/png&layers=raster_utm:layer1_utm2&styles=&url=http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?version%3D1.3.0%26
```

This does not happen in QGIS 3.0 or in AutoCAD map 2017. The CRS  used for the layer is EPSG:32634.

Comment: try switching to version 1.1.0 in the WMS box

Comment: Try toggling the IgnoreAxisOrientation setting of your connection.

Comment: it worked changing to 1.1.1 and the more explained version i founded here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23347/getmap-wms-1-1-0-vs-1-3-0?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa